# The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file

Tags: c#, unix, io

I received the above error whilst using C#'s `File.Copy` method to copy a file from a local path to a UNC path. However, it is only that path that has the problem; copying the file to any other location is fine.

I also received the error when I tried to manually copy and paste. I was able to manually create a text file in the location, but trying to modify it caused me to be greeted with the same error. However, I was allowed to overwrite it, and delete it.

I will now try reading the original file and just writing a new file (which I expect to work, but I don't consider it ideal -- EDIT: it didn't work), but I am perplexed; what could be causing this?

Possibly useful information:

- The UNC location is on a Unix system.

Comment: If you receive the error when manually pasting then surely the issue is not with your code but your environment in which case this is off topic.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is not an issue with my code. I had thought it was on-topic because it is an error encountered whilst writing software, and any answers might be useful to other developers. But if it is off-topic here, is there another place I can post?

Comment: It would be on topic if the issue only occurred in code, even then you'd need to actually show some code for it be a useful post. In this case as the error occurs in the environment independent of code then it's not on topic. I'm not overly familiar with the other Stack sites, a guess says http://unix.stackexchange.com/ would be the best. FYI if you ask the question there then I'd omit the part about your program, just the fact that you get the error when copying and pasting.

Comment: Wild guess: Antivirus.